# ffmpeg command never work in lambda function using nodejs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, ffmpeg

I am trying to implement FFmpeg video streaming functionality such as Instagram countdown functionality. In this code, first of all, I get records(URLs) from the s3 bucket and then split them according to my need, and then create the command and execute it with exec() belonging to childe_process. in this, I am trying to store the out in some specific folder in lambda function but it was never stored. I thought lambda does allow to write files locally so I am trying to do the direct upload on the s3 bucket by using the stdout parameter of exec()'s callback. guys, please help to do that. I have a question lambda does allow to write content in its local folder? or if not allow then whats the way to do that thing? I just share my code please guide me.

```
    // dependencies
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var { exec } = require('child_process');
var path = require('path')
var AWS_ACCESS_KEY = '';
var AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '';
var fs = require('fs')

s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
});

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {

    var bucket_name = "sycu-game";
    var bucketName = "sycu-test";

    //CREATE OVERLAY AND BG_VALUE PATH TO GET VALUE FROM S3
    const bgValue = (event.Records[0].bg_value).split('/');
    const overlayImage = (event.Records[0].overlay_image_url).split('/');


    var s3_bg_value = bgValue[3] + "/" + bgValue[4];
    var s3_overlay_image = overlayImage[4] + "/" + overlayImage[5] + "/" + overlayImage[6];
    const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5;


    //RETREIVE BG_VALUE FROM S3 AND CREATE URL FOR FFMPEG INPUT VALUE
    var bg_value_url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Key: s3_bg_value,
        Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
    });
    bg_value_url = bg_value_url.split("?");
    bg_value_url = bg_value_url[0];


    //RETREIVE OVERLAY IMAGE FROM S3 AND CREATE URL FOR FFMPEG INPUT VALUE   
    var overlay_image_url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Key: s3_overlay_image,
        Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
    });
    overlay_image_url = overlay_image_url.split("?");
    overlay_image_url = overlay_image_url[0];


    //MANUAL ASSIGN VARIABLE FOR FFMPEG COMMAND 
    var command,
        ExtraTimerSec = event.Records[0].timer_seconds + 5,
        TimerSec = event.Records[0].timer_seconds + 1,
        BackgroundWidth = 1080,
        BackgroundHeight = 1920,
        videoPath = (__dirname + '/tmp/' + event.Records[0].name);
    console.log("path", videoPath)
    //TEMP DIRECTORY

    var videoPath = '/media/volume-d/generatedCountdownS3/tmp/' + event.Records[0].name
    var tmpFile = fs.createWriteStream(videoPath)
    //FFMPEG COMMAND 
    if (event.Records[0].bg_type == 2) {
        if (event.Records[0].is_rotate) {
            command = ' -stream_loop -1 -t ' + ExtraTimerSec + ' -i ' + bg_value_url + ' -i ' + overlay_image_url + ' -filter_complex "color=color=0x000000@0.0:s= ' + event.Records[0].resized_box_width + 'x' + event.Records[0].resized_box_height + ',drawtext=fontcolor=' + event.Records[0].time_text_color + ':fontsize=' + event.Records[0].time_text_size + ':x=' + event.Records[0].minute_x + ':y=' + event.Records[0].minute_y + ':text=\'%{eif\\:trunc(mod(((' + TimerSec + '-if(between(t, 0, 1),1,if(gte(t,' + TimerSec + '),' + TimerSec + ',t)))/60),60))\\:d\\:2}\',drawtext=fontcolor=' + event.Records[0].time_text_color + ':fontsize=' + event.Records[0].time_text_size + ':x=' + event.Records[0].second_x + ':y=' + event.Records[0].second_y + ':text=\'%{eif\\:trunc(mod(' + TimerSec + '-if(between(t, 0, 1),1,if(gte(t,' + TimerSec + '),' + TimerSec + ',t))\,60))\\:d\\:2}\'[txt]; [txt] rotate=' + event.Records[0].box_angle + '*PI/180:fillcolor=#00000000 [rotated];[0] scale=w=' + BackgroundWidth + ':h=' + BackgroundHeight + '[t];[1] scale=w=' + BackgroundWidth + ':h=' + BackgroundHeight + '[ot];[t][ot] overlay = :x=0 :y=0 [m1];[m1][rotated]overlay = :x=' + event.Records[0].flat_box_coordinate_x + ' :y=' + event.Records[0].flat_box_coordinate_x + ' [m2]" -map "[m2]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t ' +
                ExtraTimerSec + ' -r 24 -c:a copy ' + videoPath + "";
        }
        else {
            command = ' -stream_loop -1 -t ' + ExtraTimerSec + ' -i ' + bg_value_url + ' -i ' + overlay_image_url + ' -filter_complex "color=color=0x000000@0.0:s= ' + event.Records[0].resized_box_width + 'x' + event.Records[0].resized_box_height + ',drawtext=fontcolor=' + event.Records[0].time_text_color + ':fontsize=' + event.Records[0].time_text_size + ':x=' + event.Records[0].minute_x + ':y=' + event.Records[0].minute_y + ':text=\'%{eif\\:trunc(mod(((' + TimerSec + '-if(between(t, 0, 1),1,if(gte(t,' + TimerSec + '),' + TimerSec + ',t)))/60),60))\\:d\\:2}\',drawtext=fontcolor=' + event.Records[0].time_text_color + ':fontsize=' + event.Records[0].time_text_size + ':x=' + event.Records[0].second_x + ':y=' + event.Records[0].second_y + ':text=\'%{eif\\:trunc(mod(' + TimerSec + '-if(between(t, 0, 1),1,if(gte(t,' + TimerSec + '),' + TimerSec + ',t))\,60))\\:d\\:2}\'[txt]; [txt] rotate=' + event.Records[0].box_angle + '*PI/180:fillcolor=#00000000 [rotated];[0] scale=w=' + BackgroundWidth + ':h=' + BackgroundHeight + '[t];[1] scale=w=' + BackgroundWidth + ':h=' + BackgroundHeight + '[ot];[t][ot] overlay = :x=0 :y=0 [m1];[m1][rotated]overlay = :x=' + event.Records[0].flat_box_coordinate_x + ' :y=' + event.Records[0].flat_box_coordinate_x + ' [m2]" -map "[m2]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t ' +
                ExtraTimerSec + ' -r 24 -c:a copy ' + videoPath + "";
        }
    }
    var final_command = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' + command;


    //COMMAND EXECUTE HERE

    await exec(final_command, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("data is here")
        console.log('err:', err);
        console.log('stdout:', stdout);
        console.log('stderr:', stderr);
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: "countdown/output.mp4",
            Body: stdout,
        }
        s3.upload(params).promise().then(data => {
            console.log("data is here -->", data)
        });
    });
    var tmpFile = fs.createReadStream(videoPath)
    console.log('temp file data:', tmpFile.toString())
};
```

Answer (score -2):

you can only write to the /tmp folder